# How to create script with Postgresql to parameterize the start value of a sequence

Tags: postgresql, ddl, database-sequence

I'm newbie in Postgres.
I use Pgadmin III and I need to parameterize a value in a statament of 'alter sequence'.
I have tried to execute this code:

```
select coalesce(MAX(ID)+1,1) as max into myTempTable from myTable;
EXECUTE immediate 'ALTER SEQUENCE mySequence INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH ' || max || ' MINVALUE 1 NO CYCLE';
```

but it doesn't work. What's wrong? I need to encapsulate it in a function?
Thank you. 
D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting value to sequence manually, you can use `ALTER SEQUENCE seq_name RESTART WITH value`

Regarding to your example, you need something like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE testseq;

DO $$
DECLARE
    maxid INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT coalesce(MAX(ID)+1,1) FROM myTable INTO maxid;
    EXECUTE 'ALTER SEQUENCE testseq RESTART WITH '|| maxid;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for dynamic SQL.

Just create the sequence and then change the current value:

```
create sequence mysequence increment by 1 minvalue 1 no cycle;
select setval('mysequence', (select coalesce(MAX(id)+1,1) from mytable));
```

You probably also want to make that sequence the default for that column:

```
alter table mytable alter column id
   set default nextval('mysequence');  

alter sequence mysequence owned by mytable.id;
```